# Filter with custom property - Umbraco

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco7

I have a question. I need to list the children with the "Active == true" property from a custom controller and from the .cshtml

**Controller**

```
public class PollsController : SurfaceController
{
    private List<Theme> ThemeList()
    {
        var themePageList = Umbraco.Content(CurrentPage.Id).Children.Where("¿¿¿???");
        var themeList = new List<Theme>();

        foreach (var currentTheme in themePageList)
        {
            themeList.Add(
                new Theme
                {
                    ID = currentTheme.Id,
                    Title = currentTheme.Name,
                }
                );
        }

        return themeList;
    }
}
```

And if to not filter on the controller, as I do to filter the view?

**CSHTML**

```
@model Encuestas.ViewModels.PollViewModel

@foreach (var currentTheme in Model.Themes.Where("¿¿¿???")
{
    <div>
        <p>
            <h1 style="text-align: center">@currentTheme.Title</h1>
        </p>
    </div>
}
```

**Umbraco content**

```
Polls
    Theme 1
        Question 1
            Answer 1
            Answer 2
            Answer 3
            Answer 4
        Question 2
            Answer 1
            Answer 2
            Answer 3
            Answer 4
        Question 3
            Answer 1
            Answer 2
            Answer 3
            Answer 4
    Theme 2 ==> Active == false
        Question 1
            Answer 1
            Answer 2
            Answer 3
            Answer 4
        Question 2
            Answer 1
            Answer 2
            Answer 3
            Answer 4
        Question 3
            Answer 1
            Answer 2
            Answer 3
            Answer 4
```

Thx!!!

**EDIT**

```
public ActionResult RenderPoll()
{

    var viewModel = new PollViewModel
    {
        Themes = ThemeList()
    };

    return PartialView("~/Views/Partials/_Polls.cshtml", viewModel);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
var themePageList = Umbraco.Content(CurrentPage.Id).Children.Where("¿¿¿???");
```

to

```
var themePageList = Umbraco.TypedContent(CurrentPage.Id).Children.Where(x => x.GetPropertyValue<bool>("active"));
```

`Umbraco.Content()` is a dynamic whereas `Umbraco.TypedContent()` is the type IPublishedContent.

You dont need to filter in your razor file.

Comment: Yes! this is the solution, just add Umbraco.Web and System.Linq;

Answer (score 0):

```
@model Encuestas.ViewModels.PollViewModel

@foreach (var currentTheme in Model.Themes(p => p.Active==true))
{
    <div>
        <p>
            <h1 style="text-align: center">@currentTheme.Title</h1>
        </p>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: No :( I not have ".Children" method (?

Comment: I was assuming children was an Enumerable. What type is Children.

Comment: "Themes" is a List<Theme> inside the model (PollViewModel). See the controller in post

Comment: Ok so I'm guessing the `Active` property is on the Theme object? You get the idea though right? Whatever your enumerable is use `(p => p.Active ==true)`